# How set option "Send To" from OTRS API on method TickedCreate

Tags: otrs

I want create ticket in OTRS system from my own web service and for this goal I use OTRS API ([OTRS API - merthod "Ticked created"](http://otrs.github.io/doc/api/otrs/stable/Perl/Kernel/GenericInterface/Operation/Ticket/TicketCreate.pm.html)). Work fine, but I want send email to a specific users. 

This my current options for request:

```
$options = [
        "Ticket" => [
            "Title" => "Title",
            "Queue" => "PT",
            "State" => "open",
            "Type" => 'Unclassified',
            "Priority" => "3 normal",
            "Owner" => 'admin@gmail.ru',
            // I think this options set getter email, but NO
            'CustomerUser' => 'specific_user@gmail.com',
        ],
        "Article" => [
            "SenderType" => 'agent',
            "ArticleType" => "email-external",
            "Subject" => "Subject Article",
            "Body" => "Body Article",
            "ContentType" => "text/plain; charset=utf8",
            "From" => 'admin@gmail.ru'  // from whom message
        ]
    ];
```

This screen after created ticked
[OTRS ticket created](https://nimbus.everhelper.me/client/notes/share/531877/lxn5raukkskv6n41bi7c) 

**Any idea what I can change in my $options.**

Answer (score 0):

If you create a ticket via the API, by default this will NOT trigger sending an email to the customer, not even if you set the article type as 'email-external'.

If you do want this to happen, the best way is to create a new Notification (prior to OTRS 5 this would be an 'Event Based Notification') as described here: http://otrs.github.io/doc/manual/admin/stable/en/html/administration.html#adminarea-ticket-notifications

You can match on the TicketCreate event, the user who created the ticket via the Web Service, and maybe other attributes as well.

Comment: Hello, i found this API method (http://otrs.github.io/doc/api/otrs/stable/Perl/Kernel/System/ProcessManagement/TransitionAction/TicketArticleCreate.pm.html) if you can see, this method contain option "To" may be this Method can help me? I try add them to "GenericTicketConnectorREST.yml" like this 
Provider:
  Operation:
    TicketArticleCreate:
      Description: Creates a Ticket
      MappingInbound: {}
      MappingOutbound: {}
      Type: TransitionAction::TicketArticleCreate

But after upload config, OTRS flash message 'wrong method'

Comment: You previously used the correct way to create a ticket via the web service API. If you want OTRS to send an email from the ticket to your customer, do so by creating a new notification template in the system as I stated above.

Comment: I have a problem. My cusmtomers are unregister in OTRS system and I create tickets with http://example.com/otrs/index.pl?Action=AgentTicketEmail. I just insert user`s email in a field "To customer use" to form in this page and this work.